# Sliding an activity to only a certain point (Android Studio)

Tags: android, android-activity

I have a very real question... I want to click on a button and have an activity slide up but to only halfway. Then, if I press the button again, the activity slides back down. It doesn't have to be an activity, but it should slide up like a snack bar and have information about an activity on it.

Thank You!

Answer (score 0):

As per your Question you just need an information regarding the activity, try using `Dialog` for it and design the view in a manner where upper half is the transparent color and lower half has the information or view as per your requirement. Then just open `Dialog` wherever you want.

You will need to give animation when the dialog opens

Here is the animation file: Place the animation file in `anim` folder which is in resources

**Animation file slide up:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<translate
    android:duration="500"
    android:fromYDelta="100%"
    android:toYDelta="0%" />
```

**Animation file slide down:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<translate
    android:duration="500"
    android:fromYDelta="100%"
    android:toYDelta="0%" />
```

After that add the following style in **style file**

```
 <style name="Dialog" parent="@android:style/Theme.Light.NoTitleBar">
        <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
        <item name="android:windowFullscreen">true</item>
        <item name="android:windowAnimationStyle">@style/DialogAnimation</item>

    </style>

    <style name="DialogAnimation">
        <item name="android:windowEnterAnimation">@anim/slide_up</item>
        <item name="android:windowExitAnimation">@anim/slide_down</item>
    </style>
```

After that add the `Dialog` in following way:

```
final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(this, R.style.Dialog);

        final View layout = LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.your_view, null);
        dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        if (dialog.getWindow() != null) {
            dialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(getResources().
                    getColor(R.color.transparentDark)));
        }
        dialog.setContentView(layout);
        dialog.setCancelable(false);
        dialog.show();
```

Now you will need to open the dialog as wherever you want.